# Converting SAS Mixed model with spline effect to R

Tags: r, sas, mixed-models

I am trying to run this SAS PROC MIXED model that has a random intercept and spline effect, however I now need to run the same model but in R, the code for the SAS model is:

```
proc hpmixed data = eplong  noclprint noitprint ;
    class ID;
    effect spl = spline(GA / details naturalcubic basis=tpf knotmethod=percentiles(3)); *
    model TCA = spl / s;  
    random int spl / type=un subject = ID s;  
run;
```

Below is the first 48 rows from the data that I am working with

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c("8366", "8366", "8366", 
"8366", "8367", "8367", "8367", "8367", "8368", "8368", "8368", 
"8368", "8369", "8369", "8369", "8369", "8370", "8370", "8370", 
"8370", "8371", "8371", "8371", "8371", "8372", "8372", "8372", 
"8372", "8374", "8374", "8374", "8374", "8393", "8393", "8393", 
"8393", "8394", "8394", "8394", "8394", "8395", "8395", "8395", 
"8395", "8396", "8396", "8396", "8396"), format.sas = "$"), TAC = c(79.7, 
89.4, 82.6, 93, 79.7, 123.8, 100.4, 83.9, 96.3, 80, 81.8, 87.8, 
34.4, 91.2, 80.6, 76.8, 84.8, 94.1, 81.9, 82.4, 49.4, 46.7, 54, 
NA, 86.8, 76.6, 77.4, 79.2, 85.4, 93.1, 83.7, 84.3, 100.5, 82.3, 
86.5, 81.1, 95.3, 96.5, 98.5, 94.8, 87, 87.8, 82.9, 86.1, NA, 
35.8, 43.6, NA), GA = c(11.86, 19.14, 27.86, 38.71, 12.71, 17.86, 
25.71, 35.57, 13.29, 23.29, 28.29, 37.29, 11, 17.86, 25.29, 35.14, 
12, 15.86, 24.14, 35.86, 13.86, 22.86, 30, 39.43, 13.14, 19.14, 
25.14, 34.14, 11.71, 20, 27, 36.29, 13.86, 24.71, 27.29, 35.71, 
13.71, 25.57, 28, 36, 13.86, 18.43, 27.14, 35, 12.29, 21.29, 
31.29, 38.29), visit = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 
0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 
1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried using the lme4 package with the splines package

```
lmer(TAC ~ 1 + (bs(GA, df=3) | ID), data = post.df)
```

Which gives an error stating that there are more random effects (=48) than observations (45) which is odd to me as there are 48 rows, or does it require more IDs?

I have also tried

```
lmer(TAC ~ 1 + bs(GA) + (1 | ID), data = post.df)
```

which will run without errors but I am not sure if this is having a random spline effect as it is a random intercept for each ID.
Thanks.

**EDIT**
the SAS output for the random effects is:

```
effect      spl   estimate  Std Err DF t-value Pr>|t|
Intercept ID 8366 -6.7274 11.0589 1125 -0.61 0.5431
2 spl 1 ID 8366 -5.5371 12.3271 1125 -0.45 0.6534
3 spl 2 ID 8366 0.06818 0.1409 1125 0.48 0.6287
4 spl 3 ID 8366 -0.00007 0.001157 1125 -0.06 0.9544
5 Intercept ID 8367 -8.3470 11.4438 1125 -0.73 0.4659
6 spl 1 ID 8367 -23.3954 12.9557 1125 -1.81 0.0712
7 spl 2 ID 8367 0.3962 0.1527 1125 2.59 0.0096
8 spl 3 ID 8367 -0.00374 0.001314 1125 -2.85 0.0045
9 Intercept ID 8368 8.3946 11.7727 1125 0.71 0.4760
10 spl 1 ID 8368 10.9419 12.6986 1125 0.86 0.3891
11 spl 2 ID 8368 -0.1611 0.1445 1125 -1.11 0.2652
12 spl 3 ID 8368 0.001065 0.001188 1125 0.90 0.3705
13 Intercept ID 8369 -41.4729 10.6336 1125 -3.90 0.0001
14 spl 1 ID 8369 -42.0124 11.9225 1125 -3.52 0.0004
15 spl 2 ID 8369 0.5689 0.1344 1125 4.23 <.0001
16 spl 3 ID 8369 -0.00368 0.001243 1125 -2.96 0.0032
17 Intercept ID 8370 -0.6361 10.8564 1125 -0.06 0.9533
18 spl 1 ID 8370 -0.3350 12.4578 1125 -0.03 0.9786
19 spl 2 ID 8370 0.002890 0.1455 1125 0.02 0.9842
20 spl 3 ID 8370 -0.00024 0.001273 1125 -0.19 0.8501
21 Intercept ID 8371 -24.6320 12.4400 1125 -1.98 0.0479
22 spl 1 ID 8371 -2.3020 14.2970 1125 -0.16 0.8721
23 spl 2 ID 8371 -0.08930 0.1777 1125 -0.50 0.6153
24 spl 3 ID 8371 0.001215 0.001947 1125 0.62 0.5325
25 Intercept ID 8372 -0.2713 11.7812 1125 -0.02 0.9816
26 spl 1 ID 8372 4.9727 13.1356 1125 0.38 0.7051
27 spl 2 ID 8372 -0.09524 0.1543 1125 -0.62 0.5372
28 spl 3 ID 8372 0.000628 0.001358 1125 0.46 0.6441
29 Intercept ID 8374 -3.2900 11.0061 1125 -0.30 0.7651
30 spl 1 ID 8374 -4.7893 12.1409 1125 -0.39 0.6933
31 spl 2 ID 8374 0.07259 0.1368 1125 0.53 0.5959
32 spl 3 ID 8374 -0.00069 0.001200 1125 -0.58 0.5641
33 Intercept ID 8393 10.7260 12.0891 1125 0.89 0.3751
34 spl 1 ID 8393 9.5581 13.0069 1125 0.73 0.4626
35 spl 2 ID 8393 -0.1225 0.1497 1125 -0.82 0.4133
36 spl 3 ID 8393 0.000234 0.001277 1125 0.18 0.8546
37 Intercept ID 8394 2.2753 12.0000 1125 0.19 0.8497
38 spl 1  8394 -3.6781 13.0104 1125 -0.28 0.7775
39 spl 2 ID 8394 0.08162 0.1508 1125 0.54 0.5883
40 spl 3 ID 8394 -0.00053 0.001300 1125 -0.41 0.6810
41 Intercept ID 8395 -0.3884 12.2819 1125 -0.03 0.9748
42 spl 1 ID 8395 0.5401 14.0418 1125 0.04 0.9693
43 spl 2 ID 8395 -0.01228 0.1717 1125 -0.07 0.9430
44 spl 3 ID 8395 0.000087 0.001455 1125 0.06 0.9522
45 Intercept ID 8396 -16.6502 17.6935 1125 -0.94 0.3469
46 spl 1 ID 8396 10.1673 18.3253 1125 0.55 0.5791
47 spl 2 ID 8396 -0.2815 0.2314 1125 -1.22 0.2240
48 spl 3 ID 8396 0.001955 0.001850 1125 1.06 0.2910
```

and for the fixed effects:

```
effect      spl   estimate  Std Err    DF     t-value  Pr>|t|
Intercept           93.99      2.33   1125      40.18   <.0001
spl          1       0          .       .        .        .
spl          2      -0.052     0.0197  1125     -2.64   0.0083
spl          3       0.000304  0.00004  1125    0.62   .5362
```

Comment: What is the output you get from SAS so the results from R can be compared?